# How is the second form of this sudoers command called

Tags: linux, sudo

Form 1 - who where=(as_whom) what - `lisa ALL=(ALL)  /usr/bin/passwd *, !/usr/bin/passwd root`

form 2 - who where=? - `lisa ALL= /usr/bin/passwd [a-z0-9]*, !/usr/bin/passwd root`

in the first form, regex doesn't work, only globbing, whereas second form seems to support regex, but I can't find any documentation on what's it called, only that a group specifier should be there!

Comment: The `(as_whom)` part is optional; if it is missing, the default value for it is simply `(root)`. See the **Runas_Spec** chapter in `man sudoers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man sudoers.5`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/sudoers.5.html):

> ```
> Wildcards
>
>     sudo allows shell-style wildcards (aka meta or glob characters)
>     to be used in host names, path names and command line arguments 
>     in the sudoers file.  Wildcard matching is done via the glob(3) 
>     and fnmatch(3) functions as specified by IEEE Std 1003.1 
>     (“POSIX.1”).
>
>     *         Matches any set of zero or more characters (including 
>               white space).
>
>     ?         Matches any single character (including white space).
>
>     [...]     Matches any character in the specified range.
>
>     [!...]    Matches any character not in the specified range.
>
>     \x        For any character ‘x’, evaluates to ‘x’.  This is 
>               used to escape special characters such as: ‘*’, ‘?’, 
>               ‘[’, and ‘]’.
>
>     Note that these are not regular expressions.  Unlike a regular 
>     expression there is no way to match one or more characters 
>     within a range.
> ```

That last note is interesting.  The man page goes on to describe that wildcards in command line arguments should be used with care and define some exceptions to wildcard rules.

But the reason your second line appears to support regex is because it looks very similar to some regex rules.

You expression `[a-z0-9]*` would normally mean "any number of characters in the range a-z0-9" with regex, but in this case would mean "exactly one character in the range a-z0-9 followed by any set of zero or more characters".